# Failed to get a varbinary field

Tags: php, varbinary

I need to get a varbinary field in "raw". In the database, it appears as `0x010001010DD ...` but when I get it with PHP it shows me `ýýýýýýýýýý`

```
$result = $dB->query_fetch_single( 'SELECT PentagramInfo FROM IGC_PentagramInfo WHERE AccountID = ? AND JewelPos = ?', array($_SESSION['username'], 1) );

$pentagramInfo = $result[ 'PentagramInfo' ];
```

I want to get `0x01000100DD ..` but the result is `ýýýýý`

Comment: You are getting the value as text (ASCII or UTF-8), you need to convert the raw bytes to hex using `bin2hex($pentagramInfo)`.

Comment: what is data type for PentagramInfo in database

Comment: Different database extensions handle binary data in completely different ways so you should really provide more details (at least the name of the extension and what the DBMS is). It's also unclear how you inspect `$pentagramInfo` to determine it contains `ýýýýý`. If we are talking about *binary* data, you surely can't just `echo` it.